# World clock on lock screen

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, lock-screens, clock, time-zones

Did anyone meet an app to show the time in several timezones on the lock screen?

Android 2.3.4, Xperia Pro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [WidgetLocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker) to add your favorite World clock widget to the lock screen. You can find these widgets by [searching](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=world%20clock%20widget&c=apps) the Play Store.